# Hide RadGrid column on Button press

Tags: javascript, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid with a number of columns.

I'd like to hide the second column dynamically "Ref_Name" on the press of a button.

```
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Hide" onClientClick = 'return btnClick()' />
```

This is the function btnClick() in the head of the page:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

    function btnClick() {
        RadGrid1.get_masterTableView().hideColumn(1);
    } </script>
```

However, on clicking the button, the page simply does a post back and the column is not hidden.

Is anyone able to offer any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: After you hide column put `return false;` You need to return this to stop post back.

Comment: Thanks - the button press still doesn't seem to be doing anything to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the function call... Add the return to prevent postback.

```
script type = 'text/javascript'>

function btnClick() {
    RadGrid1.get_masterTableView().hideColumn(1);
 return false;
} </script>
```

Also remove the `return` from your call in your button.